# Ember can't find template when I provide a custom templateName to a View in Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I pass a `templateName` option to a View, Ember couldn't find the template with the corresponding name. I have created a template with the name `nav-tabs.hbs` and passed `'nav-tabs'` to the `templateName` property of an `Ember.View` object.

All I get is an error about not being able to find a template with that name. When I check `Ember.TEMPLATES`, it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any chance the template is down inside a sub-directory?

Comment: Any chance of your view code?

Answer (score 3):

In the Ember-CLI world, you want to use the ES6 import syntax, and supply your template to the View's `template` property:

```
// app/views/my-view.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import Template from 'app/templates/my-template';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  template: Template
});
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? This is exactly what I'm trying to do but getting a `could not find module` error.